# Why i get 404 error trying to acess a rest?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

im getting 404 error when i try to visit an url like:

```
GET: /test/{id}
```

PS.: id is a string that changes according users filter

I have "/test" already mapped in web.xml, but i dont know how to declare some value that "i dont know", in this case, "id".

Let me show an example:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/test/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET) 
public ModelAndView testingId(@PathVariable String id ){

    System.out.println("id");

    return new ModelAndView("returns", "returns", id);
}
```

Any Help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What method are you using to configure your web application DispatcherServlet (web.xml or WebApplicationInitializer)

Your request needs to include the servlet context , servlet mapping and resource mapping. Assuming that your application is called sample.war and your DispatcherServlet is mapped to /app/* then your request should be

GET : /sample/app/test/4

Comment: this is my web.xml: web.xml

        <!-- GET -->
        <url-pattern>/test</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/test/*</url-pattern> And ir is not working...

Comment: You do not need to map /test in web.xml. Use <url-pattern>/</url-pattern> instead. If you use /test in web.xml then the full url becomes GET : /sample/test/test/4

Comment: Anything i do, i get error: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/test/abc] in DispatcherServlet with name 'test'. The String "abc" is random, depend of user filter, i cant map it. What should i do? PS.: I already used <url-pattern>/</url-pattern> with no more maps and the error persists.

Answer (score 0):

- you are returning ModelAndView, what is you ViewResolver?  By default it will try to find jsp with that name and it can't find it. Do you want to return jsp or json object?
- Does your application use SpringBoot or did you configured it with @AutoScan or configured Controller mapping?
- Put a debug statement and make sure that your request gets into the method,   debug into spring methods and you can see how Spring resolves the view.
- Id would be identifier of the resource you are trying to query. Example:    /users/123456 - user id